# Oracle Spatial transform

Tags: oracle-spatial

We have a table in an Oracle Spatial database containing polygons (lying in Austria) in Lambert projection (SRID=1000047), which we want to transform into WGS84 (SRID=8307). After performing

```
create table Table2 as (
  select ..., SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(geometry, 8307) as geometry, ...
from Table1)
```

the polygons in Table2 all lie practically on a single point north of Paris. What are we doing wrong?

***Edit:*** As an example, the point `[11.26555560027597,53.87928275206266]` gets transformed to `[2.3069645331040123,49.293822884973984]`. I get the same results using SRID=4326 instead of 8307.

The sqlplus query `select * from cs_srs where srid=100047` returns

```
PROJCS["LAMBERT",GEOGCS["GCS_MGI",DATUM["D_MGI",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.1‌55,299.1528128]], PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Decimal Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert Conformal Conic"], PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",400000], PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",13.33333333333333],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",‌​46], PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",49],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1], PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",47.5],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Comment: Have you tried using the WGS84 SRID 4326? That's the EPSG version of WGS84. Can you post an example geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source SRID (1000047) is not a standard EPSG code, neither is it any coordinate system that ships with any version of Oracle: it looks like one you defined yourself. Can you show us the definition (select * from cs_srs where srid=1000047) ?

Looking at your input (11.26555560027597,53.87928275206266) - that does not look like any projection. It looks to me like some geodetic coordinates, possibly on a different datum than WGS84.

The coordinate system definition you use is that of the standard SRID 31287:

```
PROJCS[
  "MGI / Austria Lambert",
  GEOGCS["MGI",
    DATUM["Militar-Geographische Institut",
      SPHEROID[
        "Bessel 1841",
        6377397.155,
        299.1528128,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG", "7004"]],
      TOWGS84[577.326, 90.129, 463.919, 5.137, 1.474, 5.297, 2.4232],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG", "6312"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.000000, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree (supplier to define representation)", 0.0174532925199433, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "9122"]],
    AXIS["Lat", NORTH],
    AXIS["Long", EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG", "4312"]],
  PROJECTION ["Lambert Conformal Conic"],
  PARAMETER ["Latitude_Of_Origin", 47.5],
  PARAMETER ["Central_Meridian", 13.3333333333333333],
  PARAMETER ["Standard_Parallel_1", 49.0],
  PARAMETER ["Standard_Parallel_2", 46.0],
  PARAMETER ["False_Easting", 400000.0],
  PARAMETER ["False_Northing", 400000.0],
  UNIT["metre", 1.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG", "9001"]],
  AXIS["X", NORTH],
  AXIS["Y", EAST],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG", "31287"]]
```

The main difference with yours is that yours is missing the datum shift parameters. The other difference is that the standard parallels are reversed: parallel 1 is 49 and parallel 2 is 46 vs. 46 and 49 in your definition.

Here is what I get when I transform the geometry you posted as example (encoded using 31287):

```
select sdo_cs.transform (
  sdo_geometry(2003,31287,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1),sdo_ordinate_array(607205.274999979, 528729.87700098, 607052.849999979, 528254.154000983, 607080.702999979, 528224.753000982, 607098.889999979, 528220.193000982, 607113.807999979, 528225.393000979, 607272.533999979, 528720.85100098, 607269.772999979, 528724.96700098, 607205.274999979, 528729.87700098)), 
  4326
) 
from dual;

SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(16.1442004, 48.62389, 16.1419009, 48.6196637, 16.1422641, 48.6193904, 16.1425084, 48.6193435, 16.1427132, 48.6193854, 16.1451079, 48.623787, 16.1450725, 48.6238249, 16.1442004, 48.62389))
```

The result looks fine to me. Can you verify that it is ?

What exact version of Oracle do you run? SRID 31287 exists since 10gR2.

The simplest seems to me to use srid 31287 for your data instead of the custom 100047.

Comment: The data was originally produced by a commercial tool, the customer only knows that the format is called "Lambert-Auth 47,5". Googling it led me to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31287/ which I think may be a reasonable guess.

The query returns:
`CS_NAME=Lambert, SRID=1000047, AUTH-SRID=1000047, AUTH_NAME=NULL, WKTEXT=<LONG>, CS_BOUNDS=NULL, WKTEXT3D=NULL`

Comment: In that case, the proper SRID for the input will be 31287. But then again, that is not possible if the coordinates of the geometries are like you show them (11.26555560027597,53.87928275206266). Those are geodetic coordinates, not projected.

Comment: Can you show one of the input geometries so we can understand what you actually have ? A simple SELECT <your_geometry_column> FROM <your_table> WHERE ROWNUM=1 will do.

Comment: To see the definition of your SRID 100047, use sqlplus. I need to see the exact content of the WKTEXT column.

Comment: Example input: `mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003,1000047,mdsys.sdo_point_type(null,null,null),(1, 1003, 1),(607205,274999979, 528729,87700098, 607052,849999979, 528254,154000983, 607080,702999979, 528224,753000982, 607098,889999979, 528220,193000982, 607113,807999979, 528225,393000979, 607272,533999979, 528720,85100098, 607269,772999979, 528724,96700098, 607205,274999979, 528729,87700098))`

What command would I need to run in sqlplus?

Comment: select * from cs_srs where srid=100047;

Comment: PROJCS["LAMBERT",GEOGCS["GCS_MGI",DATUM["D_MGI",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Decimal Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert Conformal Conic"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",400000],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",13.33333333333333],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",46],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",49],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",47.5],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: That is exactly the same as SRID 31287. The only difference I see with your custom definition is that the standard parallels are reversed (parallel 1 is 49 and parallel 2 is 46).

Comment: Converting the shape you gave as example (using SRID 31287) to 4326 gives:
SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 4326, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(16.1442004, 48.62389, 16.1419009, 48.6196637, 16.1422641, 48.6193904, 16.1425084, 48.6193435, 16.1427132, 48.6193854, 16.1451079, 48.623787, 16.1450725, 48.6238249, 16.1442004, 48.62389))